# Arduino non blocking Wifi connection

Tags: wifi, arduino, blocking

I'm putting a system that monitors a few sensors and based on them it turns a few lights on/off.

For further data analysis we also want to send that data to a central server, so we've added a Wifi shield. **Keep in mind that the system should be fully functional if there's no network**. So what I've done is monitor the network status in the loop() and connect again if it goes down.

Now, the problem is that Wifi.begin() blocks execution until is either connected or throws an error. **This is not acceptable since during that time the system would be unresponsive**.

I've looked into using threads in Arduino, for example [here](http://www.kwartzlab.ca/2010/09/arduino-multi-threading-librar/), but then this shows up in the Limitations:

> One of the major potential problems with this library is the fact that
>   a single Thread that gets hung will lock the entire system up, since
>   the next Thread can’t be called until the current one finishes its
>   loop() function.

So, anyone has any pointers, ideas or experience?

Thanks,

Juan

Answer (score 0):

You could create a timer interrupt that when expires kills the thread with the stalled blocking function.

Actually you may want to use an Interrupt such as [Timer1 library](http://playground.arduino.cc/code/timer1) to perform the critical updates. That way you don't need to worry about blocking code, anywhere.